# I have a problem with switch to new open window in Selenium WebDriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I must change window in api beacuse I must login in second time in the same api but with different account.
Api which I testing don`t have logout button and I need to solve the problem.
I know how to open another browser window but my code not working when I want find a locator.
I open new window but still search locator in another window not in new open.

This is my code. This code open a new window but I cant switch to new open. Mayby you can see where is the problem beacuse I don`t see :/ I read many article but not working for me.

I trying to open this driver.get(Configuration.getCSRWEBUrl()); Two times and locator is good because in similar method is working.

```
        String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> stringSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> stringIterator = stringSet.iterator();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--incognito");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        while (stringIterator.hasNext()) {
            String childWindow = stringIterator.next();

            if (!parent.equals(childWindow)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(childWindow).getTitle();
            }
        }
        driver.get(Configuration.getCSRWEBUrl());
//        while (stringIterator.hasNext()) {
//            String childWindow = stringIterator.next();
//
//            if (!parent.equals(childWindow)) {
//                driver.switchTo().window(childWindow).getTitle();
//            }
//        }
        driver.manage()
                .window()
                .maximize();
        loginPage.iLoginToTheApp2(Configuration.getLoginSecondHandForCSRWEB(), Configuration.getPasswordSecondHandForCSRWEB(), driver);
    }
```

Comment: You can force logout deleting cookie file. Or if the backend has a logout endpoint you can call it (via http request) without any logout button.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I remember it ;) I found a clue for this problem so topic is closed ;)